# How to create a loop with condition in blade

Tags: php, laravel, if-statement, laravel-blade

How to create if loop in Laravel blade to  view only images with title 'admin' only as title is  a 'required' table in uploads migration

I tried

```
  @if($imgs->title == 'admin') 
     @foreach($imgs as $img)
        <div class="carousel-item {{ $loop->first ? ' active' : '' }}"><img class="w-100 d-block" id="imgslide" src="uploads/{{ $img->name}}"  alt="Slide Image"></div>
        @endforeach
    @endif
```

but that doesn't work.

Comment: If `$imgs` is an array, then you can't access its property by `$imgs->title`

Comment: Please avoid spamming tags on your question. If it concerns Laravel, there is no point in tagging Codeigniter or Yii2.

Answer (score 0):

imgs is an collection : please try this

```php
@foreach($imgs as $img)
   @if($img->title == 'admin') 
           <div class="carousel-item {{ $loop->first ? ' active' : '' }}"><img class="w-100 d-block" id="imgslide" src="uploads/{{ $img->name}}"  alt="Slide Image"></div>
   @endif
@endforeach
```

Or you can simply query only the collections which title is admin. using where clause.  Like :

```
$imgs = Model::where('title','admin')->get();
```

Comment: Man i dont know how to thank you..I appreciate jazakallah azahar.

Comment: My pleasure. And welcome. if this really help you. Please put a upvote and accept the answer